# Ubuntu Software center does not render borders with a particular theme - Equilux

Tags: software-center, themes

I have recently installed ubuntu.

Ubuntu Software center does not render borders (pls refer screenshot) when I use the followings theme - Equilux,Adapta,Blackbird.

But when I change the theme to Adwaita-dark or Yaru, the Ubuntu software center is clean and neat.

How do I fix this ?

[image]